# Mapping csv columns to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, model, mapping

I'm creating a database of students and have the following code to read a csv file with headers and store each of the non-header lines as a student object.

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
     def self.import(file)
          CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
                Student.create! row.to_hash
          end
     end
end
```

My issue is that the csv files I need to import can be of different formats.  Some might have headers organized like:

Undegraduate Major | First Name | Last Name |  Class Year |  Undergraduate Minor

First_name  |  Last_name  | Major  | Minor

First_name | Last_name | Class_year

As you can see, not all of the fields might be present, and they definitely might not be in the same order.  How can I deal with this?

Comment: if the columns match the Student class attributes, why do you need all the columns and why do you need the columns in order?

Comment: The attribute of the student might have the name "major" but the column's name is "Undergraduate major", so it can't recognize the field "Undergraduate major" because it only knows the field "major"

Comment: you are right, sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to map the columns with attributes:

```
MAP = {
  "Undegraduate Major" => :major,
  "First Name" => :first_name,
  "Last Name" => :last_name,
  "Class Year" => :class_year,
  "Undergraduate Minor" => :minor,
  "Major" => :major,
  "Minor" => :minor,
  "Class_year" => :class_year
}

CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
  data = {}

  row.to_hash.each do |k, v|
    key = MAP[k]
    data[key] = v
  end

  Student.create! data
end
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I think this solution should work, but I'm running into the following error: "Unknown attribute " for Student".  It seems like it's reading " as an attribute, but the csv file has not " as an attribute.  Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: I think you are mapping a column to an attribute that does not exist in Student

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that, thanks!  Can you explain to me how this would behave if there was an attribute that exists in some csv files but not others.  Let's say some csv file include the attribute "minor" and some csv files have this column while others don't.  For the files that do not have this column, will the "minor" attribute just be set to null?

Comment: Yes, the attributes you don't have in te csv will be set to nil (or its default value). The order is not important. You only need to have a MAP const with all the possibilities.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please check it as the correct answer.

Comment: Isn't this very slow, if you need to do 100K records ??